# Error performing TLS handshake. The Diffie-Hellman prime sent by the server is not acceptable (not long enough)

Tags: wireless, 20.04

I upgraded my XPS 13 to 20.04 and now I cannot connect to my wifi. I reset the wireless router and set new wifi network names and passwords. My Macbook Pro can connect without issue. My wifi router is a Buffalo airstation extreme ac 1750. It's running a version of dd-wrt that's probably 5+ years old. I tried to update it through the administration tab in the routers web portal management interface, but that failed. The error message I am seeing in Ubuntu is:

> Error performing TLS handshake. The Diffie-Hellman prime sent by the server is not acceptable (not long enough).

Comment: I switched to using Google DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) and that got me connected. It seems like I'm not able to use Spectrum's DNS.